# What tool can I use to analyze ViewState in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I apologize if the same question was asked already.  I just couldn't find.  Please point me to the correct question and I close this one.

Can you suggest any tool that can help me to analyze ASP.NET ViewState?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ViewState Helper](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1342)

[ASP.NET Web Development Helper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)